# Security rules firebase, rule gets override

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a problem with my firebase security rules. I have 2 types of people. Admins and non admins. Admins can write and read everywhere. Non admins can't.

This works like a charm. But now my problem. I have one child where the admin writes regardless of another rule. I know why this is happening but I don't know how to solve it.

This rule, under agenda:

```
 ".write": "auth != null && root.child('members/'+auth.uid+'/role').val() === 'admin'",
```

The admin can write everywhere. That's good, except for one place. The rule above isn't doing anything with the rule onder approved/$key. I got why this is happening. But I want that the rule under approved/$key gets executed, even under an admin. The admin can write even if I replace 20 > 10 to 20 > 20. I don't want that the admin user checks the .write key under approved/$key

```
"agenda": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "auth != null && root.child('members/'+auth.uid+'/role').val() === 'admin'",

      "activitys": {
    "$year": {
      "$month": {
        "$day": {
          "$time": {
            "$room_id": {
              ".write" : "auth != null && (!newData.exists() && root.child('members/'+auth.uid+'/role').val() === 'admin')",

              "registrations": {
                "approved": {
                  "$key" : {
                    ".write" : "auth != null && (20 > 10) || !newData.exists())",
                    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['email', 'full_name'])",
                      //You can add individual validation for name and mail here     
                    "full_name": { ".validate": true },
                    "email": { ".validate": true },
                                    //This rule prevents validation of data with more child than defined in the 2 lines above (or more if you specify more children)
                    "$other": { ".validate": false }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Security rules cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade) so once you have allowed access you can't revoke it in a child path. You need to move your rules down to a more appropriate level rather than putting them on the root path if you want granular controls.